# empty string in python string.whitespace

Tags: python, string

I encounterd a problem the python string module that I can't understand. Why is  `'' in string.whitespace` when it is an empty string (and thus invisible)? And if it is; why it is not in `list(string.whitespace)`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. The empty string is a substring of all strings. `string.whitespace` is a string, so there's no way for `list(string.whitespace)` to produce an empty string as one of its constituent elements. The idea of "stripping the empty string" is nonsensical, but that's usually what `string.whitespace` would offer. What's your use case, exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The empty string is not invisible; it contains *nothing*. The fact that `"" in s` is true for *any* string `s` is a consequence of the fact that `""` is the identity element for string concatenation.

You can describe `x in s` as "There exist `y1`, `y2` such that `y1 + x + y2 == s`.

For `"" in s` in particular, you can choose, for example, `y1 == ""` and `y2 == s`. Since

```
y1 + "" + y2 == "" + "" + s
             == "" + s
             == s
```

then `"" in s` is true.